# How to refer to an unnamed function argument in go?

Tags: go

The name of a function parameter in go is optional. meaning the following is legal

```
func hello(string) {

    fmt.Println("Hello")
}

func main() {
    hello("there")
}
```

([Go Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/k7sePhKw4I))

How can I refer to the 1. argument (declared with a type of string) argument in the 
foo() function ?

Comment: why not just name the argument?

Comment: @JimB Ofcourse. But then I didn't have to wonder about the point of this syntactically correct form, and why it's legal or when it could be useful. That's no fun !

Comment: it can be used to satisfy an interface. You cannot refer to the argument in func hello().

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only use of unnamed parameters is when you have to define a function with a specific signature. For instance, I have this example in one of my projects:

```
type export struct {
    f func(time.Time, time.Time, string) (interface{}, error)
    folder    string
}
```

And I can use both of these functions in it:

```
func ExportEvents(from, to time.Time, name string) (interface{}, error)
func ExportContacts(from, to time.Time, _ string) (interface{}, error)
```

Even though in the case of `ExportContacts`, I do not use the `string` parameter. In fact, without naming this parameter, I have no way of using it in this function.